# How to select the records that are sharing the same Id but with different Name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below:

```
Col_Name   Col_Id  Col_Flag
  A          1        1
  A          1        2
  B          1        1
  C          2        1
  C          2        2
```

For those records, I'd like to get the result for which `Col_Id` are sharing by differnet `Col_Name`, for the example above, the desired result is to return `Col_Id` as `1`, because it is sharing by `A` and `B`, and I do not want `Col_Id = 2` get returned because only `C` is using this value.

And, the total number of the same `Col_Name` that are using the same `Col_Id` is not limited to `2`, meaning the `Col_Flag` could be larger than 2.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is very basic SQL.   Why haven't you been able to solve this on your own?   What did you try and what went wrong with it?

Comment: @TabAlleman, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT COL_ID,count(distinct COL_NAME) FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY COL_ID 
 having count(distinct COL_NAME)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT COL_ID FROM test9
 GROUP BY COL_ID
 having COUNT(DISTINCT COL_Name)>1
```

Comment: This is not correct. `A` and `B` will not be grouped before `Having`

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join on col_id and a WHERE clause to limit the output to those cases with a different col_name:

```
select distinct
    a.col_id
from
    some_table as a
    inner join some_table as b on a.col_id=b.col_id
where
    a.col_name <> b.col_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE(COL_NAME,COL_ID,COL_FLAG)
AS
(
SELECT 'A', 1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 2,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 2,2
)
SELECT COL_ID,
       COL_NAME FROM
(
SELECT COL_ID,COL_NAME,
COUNT(COL_NAME)OVER(PARTITION BY COL_ID,COL_NAME ORDER BY COL_NAME) AS UNIQENAME
FROM CTE
)DT
WHERE DT.UNIQENAME=1
```